# How to select sql database server address from drop down combobox at login page instead of hardcoding in c#?

Tags: c#, sql

I am using below code

```
public partial class Login : Form
    {
        string connectionString = @"server= SERVER ADDRESS;User id=UserName;Password=password;Initial Catalog=Databasename;Integrated Security=false";
```

Instead of coding SERVER ADDRESS in code, I want it to select from drop down as below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WbyG.jpg)

Comment: Make it a variable :             string server = "SERVER ADDRESS";
            string connectionString = string.Format(@"server={0};User id=UserName;Password=password;Initial Catalog=Databasename;Integrated Security=false", server);

Comment: Thankyou-:
  namespace ProjectName
{
    public partial class Login : Form
    {
        string server = "Server Address";
        string connectionString = string.Format(@"server={0};User id=User;Password=Password;Initial Catalog=DATABASE;Integrated Security=false");
        public Login()
        {
            InitializeComponent();  
        }

problem is i have two data bases & i want to choose one with drop down selection. how to code for that. I want to choose database connection at runtime,then proceed further with entering and validating username password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ProjectName
{
    public partial class Login : Form
    {
        string[] servers = {"Server 1 Address", "Server 2 Address"};
        string connectionString = "";
        public Login()
        {


            InitializeComponent();

            this.Load += new EventHandler(Login_Load);

        }
        private void Login_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listBox1.DataSource = servers;
            listBox1.AllowDrop = true;
            listBox1.SelectedValueChanged +=new EventHandler(listBox1_SelectedValueChanged);
        }
        private void listBox1_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            connectionString = string.Format(@"server={0};User id=User;Password=Password;Initial Catalog=DATABASE;Integrated Security=false", listBox1.Text);
        }
    }

}
```